# Supported Languages in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Is there a list avaiable of all languages (german, ...), which are supported by the forge-viewer?

I have tried to do this of there source code of the viewer.3d.js and found there an array of languages. As you can think, this way is not very convinient.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we can get supported locales from `Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Lang.getLanguages()`. It's an array. Each array item has two attributes. The `symbol` one is the language code passing `language` field to `Autodesk.Viewing.Initinalizer`, and the `label` one is a humman-readable string telling the locale language name.

```js
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Lang.getLanguages()
(21) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {symbol: 'en', label: 'English'}
1: {symbol: 'zh-Hans', label: 'Chinese Simplified'}
2: {symbol: 'zh-Hant', label: 'Chinese Traditional'}
3: {symbol: 'zh-HK', label: 'Hong Kong Traditional'}
4: {symbol: 'ja', label: 'Japanese'}
5: {symbol: 'cs', label: 'Czech'}
6: {symbol: 'ko', label: 'Korean'}
7: {symbol: 'pl', label: 'Polish'}
8: {symbol: 'ru', label: 'Russian'}
9: {symbol: 'fr', label: 'French'}
10: {symbol: 'fr-CA', label: 'Canadian French'}
11: {symbol: 'de', label: 'German'}
12: {symbol: 'it', label: 'Italian'}
13: {symbol: 'nl', label: 'Dutch'}
14: {symbol: 'es', label: 'Spanish'}
15: {symbol: 'pt-BR', label: 'Portuguese Brazil'}
16: {symbol: 'tr', label: 'Turkish'}
17: {symbol: 'sv', label: 'Swedish'}
18: {symbol: 'da', label: 'Danish'}
19: {symbol: 'no', label: 'Norwegian'}
20: {symbol: 'en-GB', label: 'British English'}
length: 21
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

**Note. It's an internal API, so it might be changed in the future. You will need to use it at your own risk.**